# NPM version command not creating git tag when the NPM app is in a sub folder

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have an Angular + Nodejs web app with the following structure.

```
my-web-app/
├─ server/ (backend)
├─ client/ (frontend)
└─ .git
```

The server and client apps obviously have different NPM configurations and everything seemed to work fine until I set up a CI/CD pipeline. The "deploy" job for the node app is basically: bump the patch version, create a git tag, git push and publish an npm package. It all seemed to work apart from one crucial thing, when I ran `npm version patch -m "Bump version to %s"` it only updated the package.json and package-lock.json, it did not commit to git and create a tag of the version number. I double-checked and `git-tag-version` is definitely set to `true` in NPM config.

After some experimentation, I discovered that irrespective of the value of git-tag-version, if your NPM app is not in the root of the repository folder structure, i.e. in the same folder as the .git folder, it just doesn't bother committing or tagging when you run `npm version [major/minor/patch] -m "commit message"`.

I think this is a bug and I can work around it by doing something like `NEW_VERSION=$(npm version patch) && git commit -am "commit message" && git tag $NEW_VERSION`

I was just wondering if this is expected behaviour and if so why and what can I do to get `npm version` to behave the same when the app is in a sub-folder when it is in the root of the repo.

Steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir my-repo
cd my-repo
mkdir my-node-app
git init
cd my-node-app
npm init  (accept defaults)
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
npm version patch -m "Bump version to %s"
git status
git log
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a npm bug. It appears if the project is in a subdirectory. There is a dirty quick fix: Create an empty .git folder alongside the package.json file then run your `npm version ...` command, for more see: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9111 and https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2010.

Comment: Thanks. I actually logged this on the NPM Github as a bug but they just closed it as "by design".